# Why do we need a sepearte table for TABLE strategy in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

My question is, why do we need a sequence table for table strategy in hibernate inheritance, which id generation must be equal to TABLE? Can't each entity use the IDENTITY column of each table?

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false)
    protected int id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the `jakarta.persistence.GenerationType` javadoc, `TABLE` is used to indicate the primary keys should be stored in an underlying database table - which is separate from the entities tables - whether you are using inheritance or not.

If you want `id` to be an `IDENTITY` column for each table you should use the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy.

Comment: If we use identity, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: What type of exception? Maybe your DBMS doesn't support IDENTITY columns, in that case you can try other generation strategies or `GenerationType.AUTO`.

Comment: I use Mysql and it supports Table strategy.